# When Fetching Data from Database Returning Empty Array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My Question Is About Fetching Data From Database But Displaying Empty Array.
I Connected DB by PDO and else you can see in code. Suggestions In Code it will great Help.

```
try{
  $tododb = new PDO('mysql:host = localhost;dbname = mytodo;charset=utf8','root','');  //Connect to the db
  $statement = $tododb->prepare('select * from todos');
  $statement->execute();
  var_dump($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
}
catch(PDOException $e){
  echo 'Exception -> ';
  var_dump($e->getMessage());
  die();
}
```

Comment: As told there is nothing wrong with your code, but the table is empty.

Comment: Can you verify that your table actually contains data? The code seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `PDOStatement:fetchAll()` returns an empty array in case your query returned no data.

It means that todos table is empty.

However, in your case it's both your inaccuracy with PDO credentials and insufficient error reporting. You didn't tell PDO to throw an exception in case of a database error.

As of parameters, [you should never ever "decorate" them](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn) adding spaces or other unnecessary stuff.

And as of error reporting, always put PDO in Exceptuion mode so it could give you a clue.

```
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];

$tododb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mytodo;charset=utf8','root','', $options);
$statement = $tododb->prepare('select * from todos');
$statement->execute();
var_dump($statement->fetchAll());
```

Comment: todos table is not empty :/

Comment: Thanks Bro It Work

Comment: If I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47989346/4932070) right, which you closed as duplicate, it is asking about inserting into database, not fetching. The question you linked to is about fetching.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what else may be failing, but in your connect, you need to remove the spaces around the '='

```
  $tododb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mytodo;charset=utf8','root','');  //Connect to the db
```