# how to access input box values that contains comma separated values and insert into database

Tags: php, pdo

This is My PHP code till now I tried

```
<?php
include_once("../include/connClass.php");
$db = new Database();
$conn = $db->getConnection();

if(isset($_POST["save"]))
{
 $date = $_POST["txtDate1"];
}

$date = $_POST["txtDate1"];
$service = $_POST["txtService1"];
$charge = $_POST["txtCharge1"];
$amount = $_POST["txtAmount1"];
$unit = $_POST["txtUnit1"];
$total = $_POST["txtTotal1"];

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($date); $i++) {

 try {
    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO backup_master (backup_date, 
backup_service, backup_charge, backup_amount, backup_unit, backup_total)
        VALUES (:backup_date, :backup_service, :backup_charge, 
 :backup_amount, :backup_unit, :backup_total)");

    $sql->bindParam(':backup_date', $date);
    $sql->bindParam(':backup_service', $service);
    $sql->bindParam(':backup_charge', $charge);
    $sql->bindParam(':backup_amount', $amount);
    $sql->bindParam(':backup_unit', $unit);
    $sql->bindParam(':backup_total', $total);

    $query = $sql->execute();
    // echo $query;
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br />Error" . $e->getMessage();
}
}
?>
```

this is my form code

```
<form method="POST" action="backend/save.php">

<input type="text" id="txtDate1" name="txtDate1">
<input type="text" id="txtService1" name="txtService1">
<input type="text" id="txtCharge1" name="txtCharge1">
<input type="text" id="txtAmount1" name="txtAmount1">
<input type="text" id="txtUnit1" name="txtUnit1">
<input type="text" id="txtTotal1" name="txtTotal1">

<button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Here is my question is I have an input boxes values with comma separated values in each input box(like abc,xyz,pqr) and I want to insert values one by one to the different rows to the database but now all comma separated values are inserting into the single row any idea how to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @YourCommonSense If I read question right, it is asking about inserting into database, not fetching. The question you linked to is about fetching.

Comment: if I fetch one by one then its easy to insert

Answer (score 1):

You can explode all the POST variables on `,` and then loop for the smallest amount of values.

Example:

```
$date = explode(",", $_POST['txtDate1']);
$unit = explode(",", $_POST['txtUnit1']);

$lowest = 1000; //Bad practice, this assumes there will never be more than 1000 comma seperated values
if (count($date) < $lowest)
    $lowest = count($date); //Loop for all values.

for ($i=0;$i<$lowest;$i++){
    //Insert records into database 1-by-1
}
```

Comment: if I insert $date into that database giving notice as    Notice: Array to string conversion  database getting Array as data.

Comment: Are You There??

Comment: same thing happening all values are inserting into the database in single row

Comment: [Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) returns an array when called, so you would have to call the `i`th number of the split up string.

Comment: one more thing do you know how to delete individual values from local storage

Comment: What kind of storage? File storage? Database storage?

Comment: text storage as here as shown form contains the comma separated values are from the local storage.